# Convolution Sum

Tags: convolution

I understand convolution is linear combination of delayed  impulses of decomposed signal.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\tau)h(t-\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau = g(t)$$

I want to know about these decomposed signals.

If I have my $g(t)$, can I decompose it in different ways? 
If yes what are those few decomposed signal?
Else, I am sure that we decompose in one way for sure. But I am not able to think in reverse way.

Please guide me. If this way of thinking is correct.

I am novice in Signal Processing.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what the formula has to do with convolution in general? It's the convolution of some $g$ with an extremely special functional $\delta$... And: what  decomposed signal are you referring to? can you give a bit of context?

Comment: (also, I removed all the tags that seemed to be completely unrelated to your question – please add back what you think is really relevant, but if you do, please at least mention these terms in your question: Don't use tags randomly.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you *don't understand convolution*

Let,
$x(t)$ : `[1 2 3 4]`
$h(t)$ : `[1 2]`

Your `decomposed signals` are now
`[1 0 0 0]`
`[0 2 0 0]`
`[0 0 3 0]`
`[0 0 0 4]`

If you were to individually apply each to the system, you'd end up with
`[1 2]`
`[0 2 4]`
`[0 0 3 6]`
`[0 0 0 4 8]`

Now a *linear combination* of these (which here is element-wise addition) yields
`[1 4 7 10 8]`

This is what your convolution equation gives you as well.

**If I have my $g(t)$, can I decompose it in different ways?**
Any way you like !
Could we write $g(t)$ above as a convolution of
$x(t)$ : `[1 4 7 10 8]`, with
$h(t)$ : `[1]` ?
If yes, do you see how your decomposed signals are now different ?
Fourier transform does something similar as well, but, it decomposes signals into sinusoids.

**If yes what are those few decomposed signal**
Try to work out the answer above.

Being helpful (since you're starting off with DSP), there is usually a good depth in definitions and a quite some detail in wordings. Try to understand each in their appropriate context to get the complete picture !
Follow this [OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MITRES_6_007S11_lec04.pdf) and good luck !

*Disclaimer : I've liberally used terms like `combination`, `decompose` and `linear`. Like @Stanley points, they are very broad and only a narrow definition is used here.*